# Wix Installer - multiple dialogs of same type in UI Sequence

Tags: wix

Background: I am writing an installer with Wix Toolset. As a UI template, I'm using WixUI_InstallDir to which I did some custom modifications (like custom dialogs etc.).

What I'm trying to do now is to add a few other steps in the installer. However, those steps would look almost identically: title, description, a few input textboxes (same for each step) and buttons next/back. Something like this:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <UI>
            <Dialog Id="SomeDialogWithInput" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.Dlg_Title)">
                <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.DlgBannerBitmap)" />
                <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
                <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="2" />
                <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="340" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.DlgDescription)" />
                <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.Dlg_Title)" />

                <!-- Some editable property (will be multiple of them) -->
                <Control Id="SomePropertyLabel" Type="Text" X="15" Y="60" Width="140" Height="18" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Some Property" />
                <Control Id="SomePropertyEdit" Type="Edit" X="160" Y="57" Width="180" Height="15" Property="MY_PROPERTY" Text="{80}" Indirect="no" />

                <!-- Dialog buttons -->
                <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />
                <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)"/>
                <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
                  <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
                </Control>
            </Dialog>
        </UI>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I would like to have 3 same steps with same inputs (for getting credentials from the user), which would differ only in the title, description and a set of Properties to which values would be saved (like STEP_1_MY_PROPERTY, STEP_2_MY_PROPERTY, STEP_3_MY_PROPERTY).

I am wondering... is there any way to create a dialog 'template' which could then be used multiple times in the UI sequence and somehow pass property names, title and description via the Publish tag? Or is creating 3 wxs files with similar dialogs the only (or easiest) way?

Comment: Only have time to send you [this link for now](https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/blob/master/WiXCustomDialog.zip). That is a zip of the project, [here is the actual project](https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/tree/master/WiXCustomDialog).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the link. I'm not sure if my question is clear enough (sorry if it's not :) ), but I already have my custom version of WIXUI_InstallDir template, where I already added a custom dialog. The question is more about possibility of creating some kind of a dynamic dialog which could be used multiple times (let's say duplicated as 2-3 steps) for getting similar credentials for multiple sources (same inputs, same labels, but different properties and different dialog description).